# numpy - how to slice of an array passed the limit of the array and back to the beginning

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

I have an image in a numpy array and I want to take the slice in red.

I expect the output to look like this.

[image]

Imagine the shape is [600,800,3]

I've tried `img[200:400,400:900,:]` the 900 being higher than the limit hoping it would wrap around but no.

I know i could also take it as two slices and then hstack them, but i cant help think there is a better way?

Its also possible that the slice could overrun horizontally or vertically or both.

Any suggestions?

Comment: While `-1` and `0` being on opposite ends of the array yet only 1 index apart implies a circular data structure, it isn't actually circular.  Using  `img[200:400, -400:100,:]` will just get you an empty array.  You're stuck stacking.

Comment: @LewisMorris -- I've posted one more answer (mentioning my reasons for doing so). I believe my first answer is not fully meeting your requirement. Let me know if you have any difficulties with the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.roll()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html?highlight=numpy%20roll), which does a cyclic permutation / cyclic shift, along the specified axis (or axes)

If the shift happens along just axis1, use:

```
new_img = np.roll (img, split, axis=1)
```

where `split` is the col value at which your image is to be split. The effect of this cyclic shift is exactly as though the image had been split at the specified point on the axis, and the two resulting image-parts have been swapped.

Since you require to shift along axis1, and simultaneously slice along axis0, it would be:

```
new_img = np.roll (img[low:high,...], split, axis=[0,1])
```

where `low` and `high` are appropriate slice boundaries along axis0.

If a shift can happen along **both** axes simultaneously (and there is on slicing), it would be:

```
new_img = np.roll (img, [split_0, split_1], axis=[0,1])
```

where `split_0` is the split point along axis0 and `split_1` is the split point along axis1

**Note:** Somewhat surprisingly, instead of returning a view, `roll()` returns a **copy**, which means it may not give much of a speed-advantage, compared to stacking / concatenating.

Comment: This doesn't address the actual slice, but does wrap the array around to where I want it. And I can work with this. thanks.

Comment: @LewisMorris -- Added the slicing part now, Note that you can "shift" along one or both axes simultaneously. Or, you can shift along one axis and slice along the other. I have covered all of these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
the_red_slice = np.tile(img, (1, 2, 1))[200:400,400:900,:]
```

The `tile` should duplicate the image at the second dimension so you can index into it. The red area should not be greater than the image width to this solution to work. see: [numpy docs: tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

Comment: @LewisMorris How so? Is there an error or invalid output?

Comment: Ah, ok i've checked again. It works on the x axis. But in my question I said its possible it would overrun both x and y.

Comment: I see now, re read the docstring also `np.tile(img, (2,2,1))[200:1400,1000:1500,:]`

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Reason for posting this additional answer:**

I realized a little late, that, viewing this problem purely as a "shifting" problem isn't fully meeting the requirement, because, after the shift, the length of the image along the shifted axis remains the same as before, while the requirement is that along axis1, both shifting and slicing needs to happen.

Let:

- `L_0` be the length of the image along axis0 (in your example, `600`)
- `L_1` be the length of the image along axis1 (in your example, `800`)
- `low_0:high_0` be the required slice along axis0 (in your example, this is probably `200:500`)
- `low_1:high_1` be the required slice along axis1 (in your example, this was `200:900`)

**Solution:**

```
# Re-compute slice-lengths, slice-starts, for both axes
len_0 = (high_0 - low_0) % L_0          # slice-length for axis0
len_1 = (high_1 - low_1) % L_1          # slice-length for axis1
low_0 = (low_0 % L_0)
low_1 = (low_1 % L_1)

new_img = np.roll(img, [-1 * low_0, -1 * low_1], axis=(0,1)) [:len_0, :len_1, :]
```

**Explanation:**

What we are essentially doing is the following steps:

1. Computing the "true" length of the slice along each axis (`len_0`, `len_1`)
2. Up-shifting the image cyclically, by `low_0` (the `-1` means upwards)
3. Left-shifting the image cyclically, by `low_1` (the `-1` means leftwards)
4. On the shifted image applying the slice `:len_0` along axis0, and the slice `:len_1` along axis1, and the full slice `:` for axis2